# Toggle icons added as invalid span attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on my website added with the code below:

```
<button class="filter-btn-open">Open <span uk-icon="chevron-down"></span></button>
```

The button has an icon added with this code: `<span uk-icon="chevron-down"></span>` for its default state.
However, I want to toggle that icon with another icon `<span uk-icon="chevron-up"></span>` when the button is clicked.
I am already changing the color of the button using the code below but I need to be able to changed the icon too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.red-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("green-btn red-btn" );
    });
});
```

The icon is however added using attribute rather than a class. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Side note: `uk-icon` is an invalid attribute for `span`. If you're going to include custom attributes, the recommendation is to use [`data-*` attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: Do you mean to use `class` instead of `uk-icon`? If not, then how is the `uk-icon` attribute being read in order to display the icon?

Comment: I want to switch the icon when the button is toggled the same way I was able to switch the style using class. I was hoping there is a way to probably change `chevron-down` to `'chevron-up` in the code -  `<span uk-icon="chevron-down"></span>`. The confusing part is that the icons are not added using simple class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click you can get the `span` element and then toggle its attribute `chevron-down chevron-up` as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.red-btn').click(function() {
    var $span = $(this).find("span");
    if ($span.attr("uk-icon") === "chevron-down") {
      $span.attr("uk-icon", "chevron-up")
    } else {
      $span.attr("uk-icon", "chevron-down")
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("green-btn red-btn");
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion and this is what I got on click `<span uk-icon="chevron-down" class="uk-icon chevron-down chevron-up">` This will not work, what I want to achieve is `<span uk-icon="chevron-up" class="uk-icon">`. That class uk-icon is added automatically by the framework script.

Comment: @atsngr my bad. I misread `chevron-down` as a class. See my updated answer.

Comment: This work perfectly. I only adjusted `var $span = $(this).find(".toggle-icon");`  to ensure that I target only a specific span. Thanks.